# Link two JavaScript files to work together on top of an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, class, import

I have homework for my programming class which requires that I work with JS classes. On top of that, I have to work with HTML and the classes have to be defined on a separate .js file. I've done all the work, and it runs ok if the classes are defined on the same .js file, but it stops working as soon as I paste the code on a different file. I've tried importing the classes on the primary file, but I could make it work (I've tried different import codes because I've found different answers to this question on Google but no one worked, that's why I'm asking here). I believe it's probably because I'm doing something wrong at importing, but I just can't find the error.

Comment: Please share all relevant code...

Comment: Sorry for the delay on an answer. I've found the solution so I'll post an answer showing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll share some code. This is my HTML head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Obligatorio1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

    <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    <script src="js/clases.js"></script>


</head>
```

This is my relevant code on the first JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load',inicio)

function inicio(){
    document.getElementById("botonAgregarPersonas").addEventListener("click",registroPersonas);
}

let personas=[];

function registroPersonas(){
    let nombre=document.getElementById("nombrePersonas").value.trim();
    let seccion=document.getElementById("seccionPersonas").value;
    let mail=document.getElementById("emailPersonas").value.trim();

    let esta=false;
    for (i=0;i<personas.length&&!esta;i++){ 
        if (nombre==personas[i].nombre) {
            esta=true;
        }
    }

    if (esta){
        alert("Nombre ya ingresado");
    }else {
        let Per = new Persona (nombre, seccion, mail);
        personas.push(Per);
        let texto=Per.nombre+" - Sección: "+Per.seccion+" - "+Per.mail;
        agregarElementoEnLista(texto);
        agregarEnComboCompras(Per.nombre);
        agregarCheckboxes(Per.nombre);
    }
}



function agregarElementoEnLista (texto){
    let nodoLi=document.createElement("LI");
    let nodoTexto=document.createTextNode(texto);
    nodoLi.appendChild(nodoTexto);
    document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(nodoLi);
```

And this is the code of my second JS file (the one with the class):

```
class Persona{
    constructor(nombre, seccion, mail){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.seccion=seccion;
        this.mail=mail;
    }
}
```

I'll start saying that, while I've found out the issue, I don't understand why does it happen.

Ok, as you can see on the last piece of code, the parameters have the same name as the class attributes. If I would try copying the code on the first JS file, it would work without any issue, but as soon as I work with that code on a separate JS file it would stop working. After touching every part of the code, I ended up changing the parameters name so it would be different than the class attributes, it looks like this now:

```
class Persona{
    constructor(_nombre, _seccion, _mail){
        this.nombre=_nombre;
        this.seccion=_seccion;
        this.mail=_mail;
    }
}
```

And that code right there works totally fine, without changing anything on the rest of the files (neither the first JS file nor the HTML one).

If anyone understands more than me on why does this happens, feel free to edit this answer.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Although your code works, keeping js files at the top of the HTML will delay the load time of the page. In a simple scenario like a homework, there's no need to worry, but in large projects it becomes crucial.

And by reading your code, it just starts when all page has already loaded, so no need to put it in the head.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! We're just starting learning coding on my college and our professors have taught us to write the script part at the top. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="first.js"></script>
    <script src="second.js"></script>

    <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did, it wasn't that, I've found the issue nevertheless so I'll post an answer.